# how to assign the video level to struct AVCodecContext in ffmpeg?

Tags: c++, ffmpeg

I am writting a C++ video encode API with ffmpeg.The video level is one important param, but I don't known how to assign it to AVCodecContext.

I read the ffmpeg document and find out that "level" is int type,below is the definition at line 3014 of file avcodec.h.

```
           /**
 3010      * level
 3011      * - encoding: Set by user.
 3012      * - decoding: Set by libavcodec.
 3013      */
 3014      int level;
 3015 #define FF_LEVEL_UNKNOWN -99
```

according to my google search, the value of level is from 1.1(1.2,1.3,2...) to 5.2, obviously it is not an int type. I think level should be an enum type,but I can't find any definition about it.

I have see some usage in internet, such as :

```
  AVCodecContect *pCtx;
  pCtx->level = 3;
  ....//or 
  pCtx->level = 50;
```

but I think these usages are wrong..
  I think the correct way to assign is somehow like this:

```
  pCtx->level = FF_LEVEL_UNKNOWN;
```

so I wonder if there is some relevant enum type definition about level and how to location it.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are encoding video with H.264 standard. By specifying the level to `FF_LEVEL_UNKNOWN`, the encoder will choose an appropriate level for you. Generally this is the best choice.

But if you have to specify the level by your self for some reasons, just multiply the real level (which maybe 1.1 or 3.1, etc) by 10. There are detailed instructions in the `Recommendation ITU-T H.264, Annex A.3` on how to select a level. And you can also learn them in encoders' code. Like `x264`, the code is located at `encoder.c`:

```
const x264_level_t *l = x264_levels;
if( h->param.i_level_idc < 0 )
{
    int maxrate_bak = h->param.rc.i_vbv_max_bitrate;
    if( h->param.rc.i_rc_method == X264_RC_ABR && h->param.rc.i_vbv_buffer_size <= 0 )
        h->param.rc.i_vbv_max_bitrate = h->param.rc.i_bitrate * 2;
    x264_sps_init( h->sps, h->param.i_sps_id, &h->param );
    do h->param.i_level_idc = l->level_idc;
        while( l[1].level_idc && x264_validate_levels( h, 0 ) && l++ );
    h->param.rc.i_vbv_max_bitrate = maxrate_bak;
}
```